# Blender FBX to Xnormal uv export not working

Tags: export, baking

I was trying to export a simple cube from Blender to Xnormal in FBX format. However, when baking it said:
The low poly model mesh has no texture coords assigned

How do I export with texture coordinates?

Comment: Did you unwrap the lowpoly prior to exporting?

Comment: Yes, I used the smart unwrap.